# Flink aggregated data as response in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-flink

I have a spring boot application. The api endpoint for example "/allData" starts a flink program within the spring boot app.

But since flink is using an unbounded data source, I am unable to get the aggregated results in the spring boot response. Is there a way I can have the flink aggregated result whenever I hit the endpoint?

Comment: Please give part of the code you are using that illustrate the behavior.

Comment: It's proprietary code hence wont be able to give it. But I just need the aggregated result when i call the API, even though the flink aggregation keeps going on in the background

Comment: Could you unless give a demonstrative code with the problem logic where we can measure the achievement  of your proposed solution?

Comment: @SpringbootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}

Comment: @RestController @RequestMapping("/job")
public class MyJob {    public void buildJob() {     final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();       env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING);      env.setParallelism(1);

Comment: KafkaSource<String> kafkaJobs = KafkaSource.<String>builder()               .setBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers).setTopics(Arrays.asList("all_jobs"))               .setProperties(properties).setGroupId(allEventsGroupID)               .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())       .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.valueOnly(StringDeserializer.class))               .build(); DataStream source = env.fromSource(kafkaJobs, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Jobs"); // Windowing method to get jobs within a 30 minute window

Comment: WindowedStream<POJO, String, TimeWindow> windowed30MinStream =  keyedStream.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(30))); // windowed30MinStream.process gives a collection as an array of objects [{}, {}] I want this data [{}, {}] from above to be sent as response to this spring boot api //execute job
    environment.execute(); return [{}, {}];  }}




Sorry for multiple messages, couldn't sent it within 1 comment

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an unbounded source with Flink, then you can't get an aggregated result. If you're looking for an aggregated result at the moment your endpoint is called, you could consider making it an bounded source. This of course depends on your source. For example, with Kafka, you could provide the starting and ending offsets.

Comment: Is QueryableState https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/queryable_state/ not helpful to get the result at the specific moment when the endpoint is hit?

Comment: Queryable State is considered end-of-life per the roadmap https://flink.apache.org/roadmap.html